# GCC 4.1.2 compiler or similar compiler for windows pc

Tags: compiler-options

I am in need of GCC 4.1.2 compiler for windows.I don't know much about compilers.If gcc compiler is not available for windows then, are there any similar compilers for windows? Any one please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the real easy way and you'll have GCC 4.x installed in 2 clicks.

Download CodeBlocks + MinGW

http://prdownload.berlios.de/codeblocks/codeblocks-13.12mingw-setup.exe

http://www.codeblocks.org/downloads/26

[Updated link:  Initially did one without mingw]

Answer (score 0):

You can go with these options :

1. [MinGW](http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php)
2. [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the two options for windows on Installing GCC Binaries webpage? It is located [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/binaries.html).